Use code generation .liquid template files from NuGet in Visual Studio
We use the Unchase Visual Studio extension to generate code from OpenAPI definitions with NSwag. We do this in multiple solutions and we have some requirements that are best solved by tweaking the NJsonSchema .liquid templates used to generate C# code.
Since I don't want various copies of the templates in different solutions across our repositories, I was hoping to add them to an internal NuGet package and use the templates in the projects that reference that NuGet package.
Reading this answer, I understand that for content items in a NuGet package, you want the files added as links to the consuming project. And then have them copied to the output folder upon building the Solution that consumes the NuGet package. However, I want the opposite. I want the files to be available (not as link!) in the Visual Studio Solution, because that is where I run Unchase to generate C# code. And preferably I don't want the files to be copied upon build, they've served their purpose inside Visual Studio, I don't need them deployed anywhere after that.
I've added the lib.props file the above answer talks about as well as this answer, but the files are still added as links and NSwag can't find them. Reading this Microsoft documentation about the .props file it seems that this customizes how the Solution is build, so maybe that's not where I customize how the NuGet files are handled?
Based on this answer about the nuspec file and the above answer about the build.props file I now have this in my nuspec:
<package>
  <metadata>
    <!-- omitted -->
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="**/*.liquid" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="NSwagTemplates\*.liquid" target="contentFiles\any\any\NSwagTemplates" />
    <file src="NSwagTemplates\*.liquid" target="content\NSwagTemplates" />
  </files>
</package>

This in my .csproj file:
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="NSwagTemplates\*.*" Pack="true" PackagePath="NSwagTemplates" />
    <None Include="Build\*.*" Pack="true" PackagePath="build"></None>
  </ItemGroup>

And this in my build\lib.props file:
<Project>
    <Target Name="CopyFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <NSwagTemplates Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\NSwagTemplates\*.*" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(NSwagTemplates)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)NSwagTemplates" SkipUnchangedFiles="false"></Copy>
    </Target>
</Project>

When updating the NuGet in the consuming Solution, building it and setting the TemplateDirectory in ConnectedService.json to "..\\..\\NSwagTemplates", Unchase fails with this message:

Generating NSwag-file for OpenAPI (Swagger)...
NSwag-file "Client.nswag" for OpenAPI (Swagger) was generated.
Generating Client Proxy for OpenAPI (Swagger) Client...
Warning:Client Proxy for OpenAPI (Swagger) Client was not generated. Error: The template directory "C:\Path\To\Solution\NSwagTemplates" does not exist.

If in stead I set "TemplateDirectory": "..\\..\\bin\\Debug\\net8.0\\NSwagTemplates" it will work, but this is suboptimal because it copies the templates to the build directory and deploys them.
What can I do to just have .liquid files from a NuGet package available in my Visual Studio project?
Updates:
The Library has <TargetFrameworks>net48;net8.0</TargetFrameworks> and the consuming project net8.0. I'm happy to only support .net 8 and higher for this. We use <PackageReference>, not packaged.config.
I've tried this from Dou Xu's answer:
    <file src="NSwagTemplates\**" target="lib\NSwagTemplates" />

But this gives warnings for all the .liquid files and the folder:

WARNING: NU5103: The folder 'lib\NSwagTemplates\Enum.liquid' under 'lib' is not recognized as a valid framework name or a supported culture identifier. Rename it to a valid framework name or culture identifier.
WARNING: NU5128: Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches in the other location. Consult the list of actions below:

Add a dependency group for NSwagTemplates0.0 to the nuspec


I've also tried with target="lib\any\NSwagTemplates" and target="lib\any\any\NSwagTemplates". Both make the warnings go away but I don't see anything in my consuming solution:


After installing this nuget package, do you see the NSwagTemplates folder in your consuming solution? If yes, right click the folder to check the absolute path then  try to use absolute path in your ConnectedService.json file.

@DouXu-MSFT I do, but it points to C:\Users\MyUsername\.nuget\etc. The ConnectedService.json is checked into Git and when my colleagues check out the repo, their NuGet cache will be in a different location. So that's also not really a workable situation.

Did you try to add <files> element in your .nuspec file only  without modifying  .csproj file and build\lib.props file?

Can you see NSwagTemplates   under your package folder  if you navigate to global-packages folder (e.g: %userprofile%.nuget\packages)?

@DouXu-MSFT Yes I see the NSwagTemplates folder under %userprofile%\.nuget\packages\_packagename_\_versionnumber_\lib and it contains the .liquid files.

Try to add <IncludeAssets>contentfiles</IncludeAssets> under PackageReference element to see if you can see NSwagTemplates  folder.

@DouXu-MSFT This breaks the build because there are also binaries in the package. I've also tried <PrivateAssets>analyzers;build</PrivateAssets> so it doesn't include contentFiles as it does by default, based on the documentation. But this makes no difference, still added as link.

Hi @asontu, I don't have some good suggestions right now, let we wait to see if anyone has any ideas.

I found a workaround to reference files included from a nuget package. Here are my test steps:
1.Run the following command to generate .nuspec .The .nuspec will display in the root of your nuget  package project.
nuget spec project_name.csproj

2 Open the manifest and add <files> element.
<files>
    <file src="NSwagTemplates\**" target="lib\NSwagTemplates" />
</files>

3.Run the following command to install this package.
nuget install packages.config

After installing the package in your consuming project, you will see the NSwagTemplates folder display in lib folder.

When you check the path, it is
C:\Path\To\Solution\PackageName\lib\NSwagTemplates\

You can try to set  the TemplateDirectory in ConnectedService.json to
"..\\..\\PackageName\\lib\\NSwagTemplates"



I've updated the question with extra info and results of trying the above. We use <PackageReference> not packages.config and any nuget install command gives error that nuget is not recognized as a cmdlet etc. even after doing Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine. I can work with the "Manage NuGet packages for solution" GUI or the Package Manager Console CLI.
